# How to find code targeting an SDK version of Xamarin iOS at compile time

Tags: xamarin, sdk, version, compatibility

My app is built against iOS 11 SDK but the deployment target is set to 9.3. So, the app builds but if I don't see that there's a code that use a method only available on iOS 11 (or a version above 9) and I run it on an iOS version 9 the app crashes. So, is there a way to get all the code incompatibility with a certain version of iOS?

Answer (score 1):

** Edit: New answer after reading title more carefully.

Xamarin iOS does not appear to define anything automatically for the deployment target.

If you must do it at compile time, you *can* define your own symbols in the compiler settings. For example you can define IS_IOS_10_OR_GREATER, then just change that for different projects.

The official advice from Xamarin is to make the determination at run time since the version of iOS you're running on is what determines capabilities. You can use conditions around code using:

```
UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(11, 0)
UIDevice.CurrentDevice.SystemVersion
```

Another option is to create an interface and have different implementations depending on the above method calls, then select which implementation accordingly. Ioc would be very useful for this.

Comment: I don't need to know this at runtime but at compile time